# Jenkins file diffs with declarative pipeline and multibranch

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scenario where I manage two pipelines within the same repo, with two different Jenkinsfiles.

I have set up two Jenkins multibranch pipelines to handle the two different Jenkinsfiles, by path discovery and set up github webhooks to trigger a build when a PR on particular branches is created.

I have not found a way to get changes in files for a particular PR so I thought of leveraging git by doing `git diff --name-status origin/master...HEAD` but it fails, since Jenkins only checks out the target branch.

The logstash:

```
using credential github-user-token-uname-pwd
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching without tags
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/myreponame # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/myreponame
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Github token in uname-pwd form used by jenkins to register and manage webhooks
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress https://github.com/myreponame +refs/heads/BRANCH-X:refs/remotes/origin/BRANCH-X
Checking out Revision 440df9b08667458fa4ade4be57ecbf59a4 (BRANCH-X)
Commit message: "move post build where it belongs"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 440df9b08667458fa4ade4be57ecbf59a4
 > git rev-list --no-walk ab28e843c0fc7807c4cbd2d6f612e5d76b # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $SECRET_ACCESS_KEY or $ACCESS_KEY_ID
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] sh
+ git diff --name-status origin/master...HEAD
```

and the error I get:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Is there a way to retrieve the files' changes of a PR within multibranch pipelines or get Jenkins to be able to discover the source branch of said PR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I had to do.
The error I was facing was due to Jenkins default checkout behaviour with multibranch pipelines: it checks out and track a branch and that branch only, it does not fetch other branches.
I eventually added

```
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }
```

and a stage that checks out all the origin remote branches

```
stage('Checking out repo'){
            steps {
                script {
                    checkout(
                        [
                            $class: 'GitSCM', 
                            branches: [[name: 'origin/FEATUREBRANCH*']], 
                            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                            extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch'], 
                            [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']], 
                            submoduleCfg: [], 
                            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'github-deploy-key', 
                            url: 'git@github.com:myawesomerepo.git']]
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch origin and then diff with FETCH_HEAD
{ git fetch origin master
git diff —name-status FETCH_HEAD...HEAD
}